# Ruby: Array to hash, without any local variables

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have an array of strings.

```
array = ["foo","bar","baz"]
```

What I'm trying to transform this into is the following:

```
{"foo"=>nil, "bar"=>nil, "baz" => nil}
```

I've been doing this with the following:

```
new_hash = {}
array.each { |k| new_hash[k] = nil }
new_hash
```

I was wondering if there's any way to accomplish this in a one-liner / without any instance variables.

Comment: This question (or very similar) may have appeared like a hundred times in SO. Why on earth was this rejected? http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/666. A to_hash/mash method is sorely needed.

Comment: `["foo","bar","baz"].product([nil]).to_h`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This would work:

```
new_hash = Hash[array.zip]
# => {"foo"=>nil, "bar"=>nil, "baz"=>nil}
```

- [`array.zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) returns `[["foo"], ["bar"], ["baz"]]`
- [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) creates a Hash from these keys

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Hash[]`:

```
1.9.3p194 :004 > Hash[%w[foo bar baz].map{|k| [k, nil]}]
 => {"foo"=>nil, "bar"=>nil, "baz"=>nil}
```

or `tap`

```
1.9.3p194 :006 > {}.tap {|h| %w[foo bar baz].each{|k| h[k] = nil}}
 => {"foo"=>nil, "bar"=>nil, "baz"=>nil}
```

Comment: I withdraw this response in favor of @Stefan's

Answer (score 1):

```
Hash[array.zip([nil].cycle)]
```

This answer is too short.

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
array.inject({}) { |new_hash, k| new_hash[k] = nil ; new_hash }
```

It's not exactly elegant, but it gets the job done.

Is there a reason you need the hash to be already initialized, though? If you just want a hash with a default value of nil, Hash.new can do that.

```
Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |i,h| h[i] = nil }
```