# How to initialize a hash with keys from an array?

Tags: ruby, hash

How to initialize a hash with keys from an array like the following?

```
keys = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ]
```

Desired hash `h` should be:

```
puts h 
# { 'a' => nil , 'b' => nil , 'c' => nil }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby: Array to hash, without any local variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620812/ruby-array-to-hash-without-any-local-variables)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here we go using [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).

```
 keys = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ]
 Hash[keys.each_with_object(nil).to_a]
 # => {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil}
```

or Using [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-product)

```
keys = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ]
Hash[keys.product([nil])]
# => {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil}
```

Comment: Getting the following error - '>> attr = Hash[keys.each_with_object(nil)]
ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash
        from (irb):29:in `[]'
        from (irb):29
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> '

Comment: @user3206440 try `Hash[keys.each_with_object(nil).to_a]`.

Comment: That method is `Hash.[]`, not `Kernel#Hash`, they are quite different methods.

Comment: How about initializing the key values to empty arrays? Something like    the following `puts h # { 'a' => [] , 'b' => [] , 'c' => [] }`

Comment: `Hash[ keys.product([ [] ]) ]` Will not do what you think! It initializes each member of the hash to the same Array value. Adding a member to one of the arrays adds the same member to all the arrays.

Answer (score 10):

Using the new (Ruby 2.1) `to_h`:

```
keys.each_with_object(nil).to_h
```

Comment: myself still in Ruby2.0.0 ... Shame on me :)

Comment: This ideas seems brilliant. Can you explain a little bit more how does each_with_object works together with to_h? I try to look on the documentation but cannot figure it out well.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative using [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
Hash[keys.zip([])]
# => {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil}
```

**Update**: As suggested by Arup Rakshit here's a performance comparison between the proposed solutions:

```
require 'fruity'

ary = *(1..10_000)

compare do
  each_with_object {  ary.each_with_object(nil).to_a  }
  product          {  ary.product([nil])  }
  zip              {  ary.zip([])  }
  map              {  ary.map { |k| [k, nil] }  }
end
```

The result:

```
Running each test once. Test will take about 1 second.
zip is faster than product by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
product is faster than each_with_object by 30.000000000000004% ± 1.0%
each_with_object is similar to map
```

Comment: create a benchmark report.. You are best on it. Lets see which one is fast.. :)

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: @ArupRakshit `zip` is faster, but for sure `each_with_index` is more clear and flexible (using `zip` you can't produce an hash like `{'a' => [], 'b' => [], ...`. My choice would be using `product` which is the best compromise, IMHO.

Comment: it is not `each_with_index`, rather `each_with_object`.. :)

Comment: Glad to see you're using my `fruity` gem :-) BTW, you didn't need to use these leading `_`.
Mmmm, gotta fix these .99999% things...

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune btw, I was just checking your code for compare_block and NamedBlockCollector, and it's one of the most beautiful things I've seen in Ruby!

Answer (score 1):

```
=> keys = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' ]
=> Hash[keys.map { |x, z| [x, z] }]
# {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil}

=> Hash[keys.map { |x| [x, nil] }]
# {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil}

=> Hash[keys.map { |x, _| [x, _] }]
# {"a"=>nil, "b"=>nil, "c"=>nil}
```

Comment: Why not just `keys.map { |k| [k, nil] }`?

Comment: or `keys.map { |k, _| [k, _] }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
x = {}
keys.map { |k, _| x[k.to_s] = _ }
```

Comment: Don't need `keys.map { |k, _| x[k.to_s] = _ }`. Rather `keys.each { |k, _| x[k.to_s] = _ }` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to initialize the hash with something specific, you could also use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) with [`Array#cycle`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

```
Hash[keys.zip([''].cycle)]
# => {"a"=>"", "b"=>"", "c"=>""}
```